# Найти уравнение по х

Tags: математика, численные-методы, уравнения

Имеется функция [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Необходимо найти решение по методу простой итерации. Как найти эквивалентную функцию по данному алгоритму? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то таких функций может быть много. В данном случае простейшая, видимо,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вполне сходится к 0.213309

Кстати, уравнение имеет единственный действительный корень — указанный строчкой выше. Есть еще комплексный корень, но это уже, как я понимаю, выходит за рамки поставленной задачи.

Если вы захотите исправить минус на плюс, ничего хорошего (сходящегося) не получится.